# How can I make a scrolling matrix terminal background?

Tags: terminal, wallpaper

There are many scripts/programs that will turn your terminal into a matrix style screensaver, however I want to use it as a terminal wallpaper and still be able to use my terminal. I haven't been able to find anything online concerning any sort of animated terminal background. Would it be especially difficult to write something that can handle this?

Comment: I would find that extemely annoying, but you you can probably just run the program from xscreensaver directly with an option to draw on the root window.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably find it fairly difficult, and there are very few examples from which you could learn how to do this.

When you say "terminal", most readers assume you are talking about something like xterm or rxvt: a terminal emulator.  Technically, Linux console is a terminal emulator as well.

Terminals draw just one character on each cell (row and column) of their window/display.  Backgrounds are what is not drawn upon: blank spaces.  Someone *could* write a character-cell application based on screen or tmux which could write **dim** characters from your animated background, while rendering "real" text normally.  Even with **dim**, you would find the result hard to read.

Some terminals have the ability to draw a graphic image as their background; some of those can simulate transparent windows by copying the root window into their window.  (This is different from the much later alpha transparency supported by certain graphic display servers).

However, those terminals which do draw a graphic image are making a *static* display, which may be updated in response to moving the terminal's window around the screen.  There's no technical reason why (aside from concerns about performance) a terminal couldn't display some animated background.  But in practice, you'll find few implementations which do *that* (few people are interested, few developers, etc).